# Git for Local Branches

Tags: git, version-control

1. How can I differentiate between two
   local branches in git ?
2. How can I copy one local branch to another local branch ?

In general how can I perform difference operation between two local branches on my server using git. I tried looking it up online but there is not enough documentation on that or there is not clear documentation on that.

Any suggestions or links to useful material would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: When u say differentiate, you want to do a git diff between branches? or you just want to know on which branch you are working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git diff` and `git merge`

Say you have two branches: master and dev

```
o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o   master
           \
            o-o-o   dev
```

and you're on dev

`git diff master`

will show you the difference between the content of dev and the content of master

`git merge master`

will merge the changes from master into dev, and your history will look like this:

```
o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o   master
           \     \
            o-o-o-o   dev
```

Comment: is there a tool/script to get a flow chart of local branches like yours? I mean extremely simple!

Answer (score 2):

1) [Easy](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff), say you want to diff your local master and a topic branch

> ```
> Comparing branches
> $ git diff topic master    (1)
> $ git diff topic..master   (2)
> $ git diff topic...master  (3)
> 1.Changes between the tips of the topic and the master branches.
> 2.Same as above.
> 3.Changes that occurred on the master branch since when the topic
> branch was started off it.
> ```

2) It's just normal [merging](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html):

> git checkout master
>   git merge topic

And resolve any conflicts via `git mergetool -t xxx`

Answer (score 0):

1) From your "source branch" use git diff

2) If you use `git checkout` all your modifications which were not committed will go to your destiny branch. If you already commit, you can use `git rebase <branch>` to get your modifications